# Combining two coefficients of restitution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

The coefficient of restitution tells you how the velocity of an object changes after a collision due to losses. If $v$ and $v'$ are the relative velocities before and after the collision then
$$e=\frac{v'}v$$
For most collisions $0<e<1$. Now imagine you have two balls and you collide them with a perfectly elastic wall. The coefficients of these collisions are given by $e_1, e_2$. If you now were to collide these two balls together, could you predict the COR for this collision? My first intuition is that $e_{12}=\min(e_1,e_2)$ since the least elastic ball limits the amount of kinetic that's available, but it also seems like it could be higher than that.

I want to know this for a particle simulator so I can give each particle a different COR and then have the particles collide with each other.

Comment: There are many candidates that should be checked empirically $$\matrix{ e = {\rm min}(e_1,e_2) \\ e = e_1 * e_2 \\ e = (e_1 e_2)/(e_1+e_2)} \\ e = 1-( (1-e_1)(1-e_2) ) $$

Comment: The coefficient of restitution is only defined for a pair of bodies. It is not the property of a single object.

Comment: @Sam You could rephrase my question like this: given the CORs of two balls that collide with an ideal wall, could you make a reasonable prediction about the COR for the two balls colliding? I don't think you can define it for a single object but perhaps you could make an approximation so you can still get a COR that is reasonable.

Comment: Perhaps this document: http://grainflow.com/index_files/Simulation_Particle_Interactions_Chap25_ed_Roco.pdf and its sources for inelastic collisions might prove useful, as some detail on the mechanism of collision is provided, together with how the coefficient of restitution may be derived. Maybe the ideas generalise for two spheres colliding.